# What is the best quick way to populate a field (in ArcGIS 10)? (for rare language/font e.g. Guzrati numerals)

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0

- I have polygons generated from shapefile (esri)  format
- I have a tiff image of plot/parcel map(this tiff has plot id scribed in somewhat
  consecutive in manner) of that polygon feature.

I would like to fill the `plot number` field by juxtaposing(placing two abreast)  the polygon and image file. I am using Arc GIS 10; what is the best way to do this?

Example: I have following tiff map, where from a polyline-shapefile has been produced by arc-scan, thereafter a polygon feature has been made from it.

[image: My dummy tiff image]

Now i want to populate "Plot No" field of polygon feature  from above tiff image.
But now "see-and-fill" method taking much more time (since 1700+ polygon/plot is many).

Under this circumstances i seek the best and quick (some what automated) way to populate "Plot No" field.

N.B. Plot No in the map is shown English Numerals, but in case of me these numbers are font that parochial (even abbey software does not support this font. e.g. Guzrati "╜")

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you perhaps re-word your question to make its meaning clearer, please?  For example, from Google, juxtaposing is present participle of jux·ta·pose which is a verb meaning to Place or deal with close together for contrasting effect: "black-and-white photos were juxtaposed with color images".  I think you are wanting to go through a folder of images and use their location to determine which polygon of an index shapefile they belong to so that their fully qualified file names can be transferred to a field of their corresponding polygon.

Comment: oh yes yes jusxtapose, i mean to place two (shapefile and image ) in screen simultaneously whereas i can see both of them.

Comment: Are your images already georeferenced?  If so, you should be able to see them in the correct position already.

Comment: Yes, image is georeferenced,but some are not, i need these image only to populate field(plot no) by see.

Comment: Can you update your question title and contents to more accurately reflect what you are trying to accomplish? The wording of the question and title are confusing.

Comment: This probably isn't much help but I did find that the type of script you are referring to is most likely called ['Gujarati'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gujarati_alphabet) and there has been [some research](http://books.google.com/books?id=WdSR9OJ0kxYC&lpg=PA73&dq=Gujarati%20ocr&pg=PA73#v=onepage&q=Gujarati%20ocr&f=false) into OCR on it so there is an off chance it might be supported in some OCR software, but you are way out there on your own on that.

Comment: Here is the [list of languages](http://finereader.abbyy.com/recognition_languages/) supported by WiseImage's OCR engine, FineReader. I do not see Guzrati or Gujarati.

Comment: @blah238, thanks for your endeavor, yes this is the problem, in this situation what can i do?

Comment: Look for OCR software that meets your requirements, or start manually entering the attribute data.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is to see an image on the screen while you are editing the index feature class to manually update the field value, then using the **Georeferencing** toolbar to choose each ungeoreferenced image and then **Fit To Display** it should let you see both juxtaposed.

Comment: Oh i do not want to see image at all, i need it only for the purpose of data input.

Comment: After taking two guesses, I'm really struggling to understand what you are trying to do - can you revise your question and perhaps include a diagram or two, please?

Answer (score 3):

Also guessing here, but if you are looking to automatically convert the text in the images to attribute data, you will need to use some kind of [optical character recognition (OCR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition). As far as I can tell, [ArcScan does not have this capability](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008D8x), but there may be [3rd party software packages](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1407&t=112286) that can do this.

From this Wikipedia article on [raster to vector conversion software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_raster_to_vector_conversion_software), [WiseImage](http://www.csoft.com/products/wiseimage_wind/) is another product that looks like it could work (has both GIS format support and text recognition (OCR) support).

That you are even doing this raises a question though. How was the raster created? Were the labels manually entered from a paper map (for example) or was that data already in a digital format and can you acquire that data? That would certainly make your life much easier.

Comment: In fact tiffs are scanned image of the "Parcel Maps" with moderate noise.

Comment: The rasters look like they were digitally created, so if you go back to the source, they should have the data you're looking for.

Comment: @ blah238, This is a sample map in absence of real.This is not digitally created, but we are going to to digitalize the map of an area.We only have a way to input data from the map.